# How to remove pages from Google Search Engine Cache

Tags: google, search, google-cache

I have deleted some of the low quality posts in my website. But that posts still available in Google search result. Can anyone know how to make Google re-cache my site?

Comment: You seem to be referring to Google's "index", rather than "cache".

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove these "deleted" pages from Google's search results:

1. Make sure these "deleted" pages return a "410 Gone", rather than the default "404 Not Found". Google will think that a 404 might be coming back so will hang on to it longer.
2. (Optional) To perhaps speed up the process you can "Remove URLs" in Google Search Console (formerly Webmaster Tools). Google Index > Remove URLs.
3. Wait. It will take time for Google to update its index. This is site dependent.

This is assuming you have no similar/alternative pages that these "deleted" pages should be *redirecting* to.